# X-Frame-Options Header Not Set: How do I set it please?

Tags: x-frame-options, clickjacking

I am using Apache server. While doing security testing, I got these error reports which says:

X-Frame-Options Header Not Set. For this I know that there are 3 types of X-Frame Options. But where do I implement the SAMEORIGIN option and how?

Header set X-Frame-Options: "SAMEORIGIN"

Tried adding the above in apache2.conf in /etc/apache2/
Tried with .htaccess file also

Restarted Apache and tried in Chrome , Developer Tools -> Networks -> Headers

No effect of new header . Please clarify how to add this header with file details.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly look for .htaccess file in the html folder in the file manager (it could be par of the hidden files) and input this code

`<If module mod_headers.c> Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN </IfModule>`

After that test again for Clickjacking